# Как получить скриншот терминала?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, консоль, putty

Есть платежный терминал в другом городе, могу подключится к нему только через сервер и в сервер по ssh подключаюсь(putty). Вопрос: как можно сделать скриншот и получить его...стоит ubuntu на терминале.

Comment: напишите прямо в вопросе (нажав [edit]), что именно в данном случае вы подразумеваете под термином «терминал».

Comment: https://www.tecmint.com/take-screenshots-in-linux-using-scrot/

Answer (score 1):

DISPLAY=:0 import

Но наверное лучше подключить к терминалу vnc.